# Adjusted Boxplot in Python

Tags: python, boxplot, outliers

For my thesis, I am trying to identify outliers in my data set. The data set is constructed of 160000 times of one variable from a real process environment. In this environment however, there can be measurements that are not actual data from the process itself but simply junk data. I would like to filter them out with I little help of literature instead of only "expert opinion".

Now I've read about the IQR method of seeing whether possible outliers lie when dealing with a symmetric distribution like the normal distribution. However, my data set is right skewed and by distribution fitting, inverse gamma and lognormal where the best fit.

So, during my search for methods for non-symmetric distributions, I found this topic on crossvalidated where user603's answer is interesting in particular: [Is there a boxplot variant for Poisson distributed data?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/13086/is-there-a-boxplot-variant-for-poisson-distributed-data)

In user603's answer, he states that an adjusted boxplot helps to identify possible outliers in your dataset and that R and Matlab have functions for this

> (There is an R implementation of this
>   (::()robustbase::adjbox()) as well as
>   a matlab one (in a library called libra)

I was wondering if there is such a function in Python. Or is there a way to calculate the medcouple (see paper in user603's answer) with python?

I really would like to see what comes out the adjusted boxplot for my data..

Comment: I'm not aware of any.  However, as both answers suggest, identifying outliers is really a separate task from displaying a boxplot.  You might just want to do some custom stats and/or plots that find whatever counts as an outlier for your particular data.

Comment: @BernBarn, Thanks for your comment. Maybe I am not reading correctly but only whubers answer suggests this right? The expert opinion has helped already a lot, but a little scientific approach would be nice i think.

Comment: Nobody knows if it is somewhere?

Answer (score 3):

In the module statsmodels.stats.stattools there is a function medcouple(), which is the measure of the skewness used in the Adjusted Boxplot.

[enter link description here](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/devel/_modules/statsmodels/stats/stattools.html)

With this variable you can calculate the interval beyond which outliers are defined.

Comment: It will help you to find an outlier borders (box plot's whiskers), but not to plot them.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible solution, following [Christophe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43088795/7745170) and addressing [@banderlog013](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7599215/banderlog013)'s comment.

1. Find parameters needed to identify outliers and to plot a boxplot:

```py
import statsmodels.api as sm
import datetime
import seaborn as sns
def adjusted_boxplot_params(data:pd.Series):
    ''' 
    Returns:
    @outlier_range_lower: lower bound of normal expected values. Everything below are outlier candidates.
    @outlier_range_upper: upper bound of normal expected values. Above are outlier candidates.
    @whis: (lowWhis,highWhis) whis parameter for the boxplot method, in a form (low_percentage, high_percentage), as expected by pyplot.boxplot().
    '''

    q1 = data.quantile(0.25)
    q3 = data.quantile(0.75)

    # Calculate the interquartile range
    iqr = q3 - q1
    #calculate medcouple
    y = np.asarray(data, dtype=np.double) 
    MC = sm.stats.stattools.medcouple(y) 

    # Define the outlier range 
    if (MC>0):
        outlier_range_lower = q1 - 1.5 * np.exp(-4*MC) * iqr
        outlier_range_upper = q3 + 1.5 * np.exp(3*MC)  * iqr
    else:
        outlier_range_lower = q1 - 1.5 * np.exp(-3*MC) * iqr
        outlier_range_upper = q3 + 1.5 * np.exp(4*MC)  * iqr

    whis = np.interp([outlier_range_lower, outlier_range_upper], np.sort(data), np.linspace(0, 1, data.size)) * 100 #Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65390045/7745170

    return outlier_range_lower, outlier_range_upper, whis
```

2. Select outliers from a dataframe column and optionally plot an adjusted boxplot:

```py
def select_outliers_adjusted_boxplot(df, col_name:str,show_plot=False): 
    ''' selects rows in the dataframe df which coll_name falls out of bounds [min,max]
    @df: dataframe 
    @col_name: column to analyze 
    Returns:
    @otuliers: df with selected rows from input df.
    '''

    outlier_range_lower, outlier_range_upper, whis = adjusted_boxplot_params(df[col_name])
    # Select the rows where the duration is outside the outlier range
    outliers = df[(df[col_name] < outlier_range_lower) |
                  (df[col_name] > outlier_range_upper)]

    if show_plot==True:
        plot = sns.boxplot(x=df[col_name,whis=whis)
        plt.show(plot2)

    # Return the DataFrame containing the outliers
    return outliers
```