# Customize the value of whiskers in boxplot, python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot a boxplot with mean+(-) 2* std as the cap values of Whisker. However, boxplot() can only set cap values of whiskers as the values of percentiles. e.g.

```
# The code below plot a boxplot that has cap values equal to 5th and 95th percentiles. 
boxplot(data_list,Whis = [5,95])
```

Given my distribution is not a normal distribution, then the 95th/5th percentiles will not be the (mean+2*std)/(mean-2*std).
Therefore, it is inaccurate to use 5/95th percentiles values to represent mean+(-) 2*std.

My question is how can I customers a boxplot with the customized cap values of whiskers?
Thank you so much

Comment: Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial.

Comment: I don't think boxplot can customer the values of Whisker. So this why I asked in here.

Comment: If you don't think they can be customized why did you ask.  Read through the [Matplotlib Tutorials](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/index.html) - almost everything can be customized, Whiskers are `Artists` - they have properties and methods.

Comment: Were any of the *solutions* from the [Boxplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/gallery/statistics/boxplot_demo.html#boxplots) example in the gallery helpful?

Comment: There is a link to the source in [the boxplot documentation](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.boxplot.html) - you should be able to see how the whiskers are calculated and positioned, that should give you a starting point.

Comment: Thanks, man. I read the tutorial and documentation multiple times. I wonder if there is a way to create boxplot with customized whiskers values?

Comment: Sorry man, I do not think I make my question clear. My question is the cap value of boxplot (The end of Whiskers) can only be set as the value of percentiles. However, I want to set the cap value as the mean +(-) 2*std. mean +(-) 2*std not equal to any percentile values. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib provides no means to specify the whiskers otherwise than as quantiles. If you want to used mean and ± 2 times standard deviation you'll need to roll your own, i.e. converte these values to percentiles and provide them as `whis` paramters.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

np.random.seed(42)
data = np.random.normal(size=10_000)

mean = np.mean(data)
std = np.std(data)
whis = np.interp([mean-2*std, mean+2*std], np.sort(data), np.linspace(0,1,data.size)) * 100

fig, (axl,axr) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)
axl.set_title('Default')
axl.boxplot(data)
axr.set_title(f'μ ± 2σ ({mean-2*std:.2f}, {mean+2*std:.2f})')
axr.boxplot(data, whis=whis, usermedians=[mean])
```

[image]

There is one caveat: the whiskers are not drawn from the given first to the given second percentile value (parameter `whis`) but rather from the lowest data point above the first to the highest data point below the second percentile value. This is why for relatively small data sets the whiskers ends in the plot to not excactly match μ ± 2σ.

But be aware that this is **not a box and whiskers plot anymore**, so you should clearly **describe what you're plotting here, otherwise people will be mislead.**

Comment: the code is nice and clean (so +1). I also find the whiskers not intuitive and use a custom drawn boxplot (but in MATLAB). Anyway: One word of warning (mostly to the OP), I prefer whiskers to be at the 5% & 95% quantile. It might be hard to read if a boxplot does not represent quantiles but multiples of the standard deviation (of which one hopes to have a Gaussian distribution of the data...)