# Why are the whiskers not displayed correctly with boxplots?

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I would like to plot a boxplot for columns of a dataframe which have percentages and to set the
lower limit to 0 and the upper limit to 100 to detect visually the outliers. However I didn't succeed in plotting the whiskers correctly.
Here I created a column with random percentages with some outliers.

```
import random
from random import randint

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

random.seed(42)
lst=[]
for x in range(140):
    x=randint(1,100)
    lst.append(x)
lst.append(-1)
lst.append(300)
lst.append(140)
print(lst)

df = pd.DataFrame({0:lst})
```

Here is my function:

```
def boxplot(df,var,lower_limit=None,upper_limit=None):
    
    q1=df[var].quantile(0.25)
    q3=df[var].quantile(0.75)
    iqr=q3-q1
    w1=w2=1.5
    
    if (q1!=q3) and (lower_limit!=None):
        w1=(q1-lower_limit)/iqr
    
    if (q1!=q3) and (upper_limit!=None):
        w2=(upper_limit-q3)/iqr
    
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    df.boxplot(column=var,whis=(w1,w2))
    plt.show()
    
    print(f'The minimum of {var} is',df[var].min(),'and its maximum is ',df[var].max(),"\n")
    print(f'The first quantile of {var} is ',q1,'its median is ',df[var].median(),'and its third quantile is ',q3,"\n")
```

I coded `boxplot(df,0,lower_limit=0,upper_limit=100)` and I had this result:
[image: Result of the function]

But the whiskers don't go to 100 and I would like to know why.

Comment: DF is never initialized in your provided code. Can you share what is in the vaariable df?

Comment: @PirateX I added something that I think will reproduce the plot now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TLDR**: I don't think you can do what you want to do.  The whiskers must snap to values within your dataset, and cannot be set arbitrarily.

Here is a good reference post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/65390045/13386979.

---

First of all, kudos on a nice first post.  It is great that you provided code to reproduce your problem  There were a few small syntax errors, see my edit.

My impression is that what you want to do is not possible with the matplotlib boxplot (which is called by `df.boxplot`).  One issue is that the units of the `whis` parameter (when you pass a pair of floats) are in percentiles. Taken from the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot.html#matplotlib.pyplot.boxplot):

> If a pair of floats, they indicate the percentiles at which to draw the whiskers (e.g., (5, 95)). In particular, setting this to (0, 100) results in whiskers covering the whole range of the data.

When you pass `lower_limit=0, upper_limit=100` to your function, you end up with `w1 == 0.5490196078431373` and `w2 == 0.4117647058823529` (you can add a print statement to verify this).  This tells the boxplot to extend whiskers to the 0.5th and 0.4th percentile, which are both very small (the boxplot edges are the 25th to 75th percentile).  The latter is smaller than the 75th percentile, so the top whisker is drawn at the upper edge of the box.

It seems that you have based your calculation of `w1` and `w2` based on this section from the documentation:

> If a float, the lower whisker is at the lowest datum above Q1 - whis*(Q3-Q1), and the upper whisker at the highest datum below Q3 + whis*(Q3-Q1), where Q1 and Q3 are the first and third quartiles. The default value of whis = 1.5 corresponds to Tukey's original definition of boxplots.

I say this because if you also print `q1 - w1 * iqr` and `q3 + w2 * iqr` within your call, you get `0` and `100` (respectively).  But this calculation is only relevant when a single float is passed (not a pair).

But okay, then what can you pass to `whis` to get the limits to be any arbitrary value?  This is the real problem: I don't think this is possible. The percentiles will always be a value in your data set (there is no interpolation between points).  Thus, the edges of the whiskers always snap to a point in your dataset.  If you have a point near 0 and near 100, you could find the corresponding percentile to place the whisker there.  But without a point there, you cannot hack the `whis` parameter to set the limits arbitrarily.

I think to fully implement what you want, you should look into drawing the boxes and whiskers manually.  Though the caution shared in the other post I referenced is also relevant here:

> But be aware that this is not a box and whiskers plot anymore, so you should clearly describe what you're plotting here, otherwise people will be mislead.

Comment: Ok thank you very much! Yes you are right I was inspired by the documentation with Q1 - whis*(Q3-Q1) and Q3 + whis*(Q3-Q1) but I didn't know that the whiskers parameters were related to the percentile now I better understand. I will code a function which draws the boxes and the whiskers manually and look at the post you put.